# On the little oh notation.

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I have been told that in a fraction if we only have little ohs then we can't conclude anything taking the limit.

As an example say we have $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{o(x^3)}{o(x^2)}$$ then we can't conclude anything but this confuses me slightly because it seems to me we should be able to say that the limit goes to zero.

I mean we have
$$0 = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^4}{x^3} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{o(x^3)}{o(x^2)} $$

Could somebody kindly explain to me the reasons why we can't conclude what the limit is when we have only little oh notation as in my above example?

Comment: I think the point is that little-oh notation only tells us the behaviour of functions when $x$ is sufficiently *large* and gives no information for when $x#$ approaches 0

Comment: @DavidSteinberg There is a little-oh notation for infinitesimals, which is rather common in analysis and physics. To be fair, I saw it more often that the one for infinities.

Comment: I assume your little oh notation means that the quantity, when divided by the argument, vanishes as $x$ goes to zero. The problem is that the convergence rate could be much slower in the numerator than in the denominator. For instance $x^4$ is $o(x^3)$ and $x^5$ is $o(x^2)$, and for these representatives the ratio is $\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

I am just expanding on Ian's comment here.

If we assume that the definition $h(x)=o(x^n)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ means $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{h(x)}{x^n}=0$ then your limit can be interpreted as $$lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ for some $f(x),g(x)$ such that $f(x)=o(x^3)$ and $g(x)=o(x^2)$.

Using the definition then you could take $f(x)=x^4$ and $g(x)=x^3$ and the limit would go to $0$.

Or you could take $f(x)=x^4$ and $g(x)=x^5$ and the limit would go to $\infty$.

Again $f(x)=x^4$ and $g(x)=x^4$ and the limit would go to $1$ and that's why you really cannot conclude anything.